# No event information is returned with the queryEvent REST API in IBM Watson IoT Map Insights

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, iot-context-mapping

I referred to the document of IBM Watson IoT Map Insights (https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/apidocs/123) and tried to use the queryEvent REST API as follows. But no event information was returned...

-Request-type:GET, url: https://automotive.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/mapinsights/eventservice/event/query?tenant_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

-Return body:  []  <--- No event information was returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the area information (min/max_longitude, min/max_latitude) with the tenant_id to the queryEvents API in order to get the correct result. That is, the area information parameters are mandatory. We will update the document in next release. Thank you.

For example:
Request-type: GET
https://automotive.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/mapinsights/eventservice/event/query?tenant_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&min_logitude=xxx&min_latitude=xxx&max_longitude=xxx&max_latitude=xxxb